# Restrict (Deny) Bucket List by IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket policy that works properly to restrict access to a bucket to certain IP's, but I actually want to deny listing the bucket itself or bucket(s) to only certain IP's.

I got it working with everything except the listing. I can deny listing the bucket contents, uploading, downloading, but can't deny doing a simple command like `Get-S3Bucket -BucketName "bucket"`

My current policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "bucket-policy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPDeny",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": ["1.2.3.4.5","6.7.8.9"]
          }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This does work for doing an `aws s3 ls s3://bucketName` but doesn't restrict the PowerShell module `Get-S3Bucket -name "bucketName"`

Comment: `aws s3 ls s3://bucketName` shows objects in it (list up objects) but `Get-S3Bucket -name "bucketName"` shows bucket itself only. it is like `aws s3 ls`, which shows list of buckets includes the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was specific to PowerShell Toolkit. Which I learned the `Get-S3Bucket` actually runs an **"s3 collection"** which I believe to include the following:

```
s3:ListBucket,
s3:ListAllMyBuckets,
s3:HeadBucket
```

So the issue for me wasn't the bucket policy, it was the IAM user policy.

I solved it via the **user policy** like follows:

```
{
      "Sid": "listBuckets",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
          "s3:HeadBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": ["1.2.3.4","5.6.7.8"]
          }
        }
      }
```